# Evaluate limit $a^xx^a$ where 0<a<1

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to evaluate the limit:$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^aa^x} $$ where $0<a<1$

I put in Wolfram Alpha and I get the limit is zero

We see if the base is $0<a<1$ then :
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{a^x} =0$$

I tried to solve the limit with a teorem that says : $$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 0$$ and $$g(x)$$ is a bounded .
Then  $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)g(x)=0$$

But $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^a} =\infty$$

and the product of $\infty$ and $0$ is undefined

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yes I allowed to use L'Hôpital rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general result.

> **Theorem (Domination of exponentials and polynomials):** 
>   Let $a, b>0$.
>   Then
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^a}{b^x} =
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
> +\infty&\text{if $\,b\leqslant 1$}\\
> 0&\text{if $\,b> 1$}\\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

*Proof:*
If $b\leqslant 1$ then $b^x\leqslant 1$ for all $x\geqslant 1$ and hence for $x\geqslant 1$ we have
$$
\frac{x^a}{b^x} \geqslant x^a \stackrel{x\to\infty}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{1cm}}}+\infty.
$$
If $b>1$ then $b^x \to+\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, so we may apply L'Hôpital's rule.
Observing that $b^x = \exp\big(x\log (b)\big)$, we'll obtain that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^a}{b^x} =
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{a}{\log(b)}\frac{x^{a-1}}{b^x}
$$
Notice that up to the positive constant $a/\log (b)$, we arrive at the same limit we began with, except the initial value of the exponent $a$ in the polynomial term has decreased by $1$.
We can successively apply L'Hôpital's rule until the exponent becomes non-positive, at which point the limit is easily seen to be $0$. $\square$

---

For your particular question, we can apply the general result with $b=\frac1a > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1+t$ then [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) shows
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^aa^x}=\lim_{t \to \infty}{(1+t)^aa^{1+t}}>\lim_{t \to \infty}{(at)a^{1+t}}=a^2\lim_{t \to \infty}{ta^{t}}=0$$
the last one holds by L'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y=a^x \,x^a \implies \log(y)=a \log(x)+x \log(a)=x \left(a\frac{ \log (x)}{x}+\log (a)\right)$$ Since $x\to \infty$, $\frac{ \log (x)}{x}$ is negligible for any $a$. So
$$\log(y) \sim x \log(a)$$ and, since $0 < a < 1$, $\log(a) <0$. Then $\log(y)\to -\infty$ and $y=e^{log(y)} \to 0$